# Numpy arrays and comparisons with different values

Tags: python-3.x, csv, numpy, numpy-ndarray

For reproducibility reasons, I am sharing the data [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EoZCwW54fCrl0uB4m15yZzimaQXJ-QW_).

From column 2, I wanted to read the current row and compare it with the value of the previous row. If it is greater, I keep comparing. If the current value is smaller than the previous row's value, I want to divide the current value (smaller) by the previous value (larger). Accordingly, the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

protocols = {}

types = {"data_c": "data_c.csv", "data_r": "data_r.csv", "data_v": "data_v.csv"}

for protname, fname in types.items():
    col_time,col_window = np.loadtxt(fname,delimiter=',').T
    trailing_window = col_window[:-1] # "past" values at a given index
    leading_window  = col_window[1:]  # "current values at a given index
    decreasing_inds = np.where(leading_window < trailing_window)[0]
    quotient = leading_window[decreasing_inds]/trailing_window[decreasing_inds]
    quotient_times = col_time[decreasing_inds]

    protocols[protname] = {
        "col_time": col_time,
        "col_window": col_window,
        "quotient_times": quotient_times,
        "quotient": quotient,
    }
```

`data_c` is a `numpy.array` that has only one **unique** `quotient` value `0.7`, as does `data_r` with a unique `quotient` value of `0.5`. However, `data_v` has two unique `quotient` values (either `0.5` or `0.8`).

I wanted to loop through the `quotient` values of these CSV files and categorize them using a simple `if-else` statement. I get help from one StackOverflow contributor using [numpy.array_equal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html) as the following.

```
import numpy as np
unique_quotient = np.unique(quotient)
unique_data_c_quotient = np.r_[ 0.7]
unique_data_r_quotient = np.r_[ 0.5]

if np.array_equal( unique_quotient, unique_data_c_quotient ): 
    print('data_c')
elif np.array_equal( unique_quotient, unique_data_c_quotient ):
    print('data_r')
```

This perfectly works for `data_c` and `data_r` whose values are 0.7 and 0.5 respectively. This means it works only when the `quotient` value is unique (or fixed). However, it doesn't work when the `quotient` value is more than one. For example, `data_m` has quotient values between 0.65 and 0.7 (i.e. `0.65<=quotient<=0.7`) and `data_v` has two `quotient` values (0.5 and 0.8)

How can we solve this issue using `numpy arrays`?

Answer (score 0):

If you consistently have unique quotients, and consistently have unique quotient bounds then I would recommend the following:

```
ud_m_bounds = np.r_[0.65,0.7]

uq = unique_quotient
uq_min,uq_max = uq.min(),uq.max()

def is_uq_bounded_by(unique_data_bounds):
  ud_min,ud_max = unique_data_bounds.min(), unique_data_bounds.max()
  left_bounded  = ud_min <= uq_min <= ud_max
  right_bounded = ud_min <= uq_max <= ud_max
  bounded = left_bounded & right_bounded
  return bounded

label = 'ERROR -- DATA UNCLASSIFIED'
if len(uq) > 2:
  if is_uq_bounded_by( unique_data_m_bounds ):
    label = 'data_m'
elif 0 < len(uq) <= 2:
  if np.array_equal( uq, unique_data_v_quotient):
    label = 'data_v' 
  if np.array_equal( uq, unique_data_c_quotient):
    label = 'data_c'
  elif np.array_equal( uq, unique_data_r_quotient):
    label = 'data_r'
print(label)
```

Note that the method becomes dubious when the data begin to overlap.